# Obter json através de ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-service

Tenho um *webservice* desenvolvido em Java que é responsável por devolver todas as composições de determinado tecido/peça (área têxtil).

O *webservice* está a devolver em primeiro lugar a composição já previamente existente, ou seja, como o *webservice* é usado em particular na página que vai permitir atualizar determinado artigo, é necessário obter primeiro o desenho atual e, posteriormente, os restantes. Até aqui não existe qualquer problema.

A parte que tentei atrás explicar pertence ao *backend*. O problema reside no *frontend*, mais concretamente na página que é responsável por atualizar um artigo. Um artigo pode ser descrito como um produto, que foi já projetado, e/ou planejado e que está em catálogo. Face a isto, como disse anteriormente, eu tenho que mostrar previamente os valores dos atributos de um artigo. Observem abaixo que o artigo com a `ref "UL ..."` tem já alguns valores preenchidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema ocorre, como dizia, no momento em que tento obter composição. Mostro abaixo o código que tentei implementar e que está a dar problemas:

```
function populate(frm,data) {


    var out="";
    for (var key in data) {
if(key == "composicao")
        {
            out=encodeURI(data[key]);

            var uri="http://127.0.0.1:8080/revistaSystem/resplaneamento/ServicoComposicao/ObterTodasAsComposicoes/";
            var urifinal = uri.concat(out);
            alert(urifinal);

                    $.ajax({
                             url:urifinal,
                             complete: function (response) {
                             var data=response.responseText;
                             alert(data);           
                             var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);

                             var $select = $('#composicao');

                             $select.empty();

                             $(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
                                var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.numPK).text(o.composicao);
                                $select.append($option);
                            });

                                //preencher option

                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an 1error!');
                            },
                    });
        }   
            }
```

Face a isto, no caso de composição em particular, existe a necessidade de codificar o parâmetro (a *string* que entra como parâmetro), pois uma composição, de determinado tecido, pode ser singela ou composta, ou seja:

1. 100% Algodão (Composição singela)
2. 30% Algodão/60% Linho (Composicao composta)

Face a que um artigo pode ter uma composição composta, o mesmo é sempre separado por uma `"/"`. Aqui ocorre o problema. O *webservice* retoma sempre um JSON para ser interpretado através de JavaScript/AJAX, mas do lado do *frontend* não consigo obter o JSON, apenas estou a conseguir obter, a seguinte mensagem (erro):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Valor retomado pelo *webservice*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Sua resposta foi um HTTP 404, *Not Found*, então inicie verificando a rota utilizada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a rota para o webservice está correta

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o problema encontrava-se mesmo na codificação do parametro que eu tenho que passar em cada URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema encontrava-se na codificação do parametro, como eu desconfiava, assim efetuei os seguintes passos:

1: Implementei uma nova função similar a função urlencode() que existe para o php, e que por acaso eu tambem usava neste projeto.

```
   function urlencode(text) {
        return encodeURIComponent(text).replace(/!/g,  '%21')
                                       .replace(/'/g,  '%27')
                                       .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
                                       .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
                                       .replace(/\*/g, '%2A')
                                       .replace(/%20/g, '+');
    }
```

2:Tendo em conta que a variavel `out` recebe um valor que é usado como parametro, efetuei tambem esta alteração:

```
out=urlencode(data[key]);
```

Problema resolvido :)